# Last Segment before the question mark ( ? ) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the URL

`http://localhost:8080/BIM/teacher/reports/section-exercise/assignment?assessmentId=206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3&classroomId=722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a`

I want to grab the last segment of my URL before the `?`, ignore what after the `?`

Can someone please teach me how to do that ?

I've tried

```
var href = location.href;
var lastSegment = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
console.log(lastSegment);
```

I got

assignment?assessmentId=206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3&classroomId=722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a

I only want **assignment**

Comment: Is this the browser URL (`document.location`), an `href` attribute or just a string?

Comment: sorry ab that, `var href = location.href ; `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
var pathParts = location.pathname.split('/'),
    basename = pathParts[pathParts.length - 1];
```

---

Or this super handy one-liner (sometimes I have to remind myself that arrays have methods)

```
var basename = location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

See [`URLUtils.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/pathname)

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. It really helps me see the different.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lastSegment = href.substring(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, href.lastIndexOf('?'));
```

You have to also limit your end - and use substring instead of substr.

Here's a fiddle too ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/jf2xrahx/

Comment: You could use `location.pathname` instead of `location.href`, so you don't have to look for `?`.

Comment: @Barmar : Feel free to throw in your answer here too so we call can learn from you, mate :)

Comment: I actually like @Phil's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `String.prototype.match()`

```js
var url = "http://localhost:8080/BIM/teacher/reports/section-exercise/assignment?assessmentId=206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3&classroomId=722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a";
var res = url.match(/\w+\?/)[0].slice(0, -1);
document.write(res);
```